# How to convert HTML to PDF (with Images!) (PHP or JS)

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Do you know how to convert HTML to PDF with images (JPG/PNG) ?
i try use jsPDF but convert just a text without images :(

CODE:

```
    <!--
    content of this area will be the content of your PDF file
    -->
    <div id="HTMLtoPDF">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
            </tr>  
          </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>

    <!-- here we call the function that makes PDF -->
    <a href="#" onclick="HTMLtoPDF()">Download PDF</a>

    <!-- these js files are used for making PDF -->
        <script src="js/png.js"></script>
    <script src="js/addimage.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jspdf.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pdfFromHTML.js"></script>
```

What do you mean? I want create invoice

Comment: I forgot paste <img src="logo.png">

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).